# Performance measuring of for loop without n

Tags: algorithm, performance, for-loop, big-o, complexity-theory

I'm wondering what the complexity of a for loop that iterates everytime it is called from 1 to 10 without depending on input is.

Here is a example - n is input:

```
int count = 0;
int max = n + 1;

for (int a = 1; a < max; a++)
{
   for (int b = 1; b < a; b++)
   {
     for (int c = 1; c < 10; c++)
     {
      count = count + 1
     }
   }
}
return count
```

So I was thinking that the complexity of the inner for loop is 1 while the other to is each n+1? 
=>   1+1+(n+1)*(1+(n+1)*(1+1+1))+1 = 3n²+7n+7

or is it 10 because of the ten iterations?
=>   1+1+(n+1)*(1+(n+1)*(1+10+10))+1 = 21n²+43n+25

So basically after leaving the constants away it is a complexity of O(n²)

I'm new into measuring complexity, so I'm really thankful for every help.

Thanks,

Greets & happy new year

Comment: You are right, the innermost loop has a constant run time, hence O(1).

Answer (score 0):

If your loop is always executed some fixed number of times, it doesn't influence complexity, because you can 'unroll' it:

```
for (int a = 1; a < max; a++)
{
    for (int b = 1; b < a; b++)
    {
        count = count + 1  // c = 1
        count = count + 1  // c = 2
        count = count + 1  // c = 3
        count = count + 1  // c = 4
        count = count + 1  // c = 5
        count = count + 1  // c = 6
        count = count + 1  // c = 7
        count = count + 1  // c = 8
        count = count + 1  // c = 9
    }
}
```

The program you get has exactly the same semantics as the first one and the same big O complexity.

**À propos**

"Loop unrolling" is one of the optimisations used by C/C++ compilers. E.g. in GCC you turn it on with `-funroll-loops` flag.

> **-funroll-loops**
>
> Unroll loops whose number of iterations can be determined at compile time or upon entry to the loop. `-funroll-loops` implies `-frerun-cse-after-loop`. This option makes code larger, and may or may not make it run faster.

source: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.2/gcc/Optimize-Options.html